# how can i use wss in node.js, if the https server is a separate node.js application?

Tags: node.js, ws

I've created a multiplayer game with websockets in nodejs (using the ws lib), which works just fine. For debugging, I connected to the websocket server with my client webpage by just opening the html file via file:// protocol.

I wanted to have the page hosted on my web-server which uses https. This web-server also uses nodejs, but because the webpage is served via https, it cannot create a connection via ws and needs wss. Security downgrading and so on.

[image]

My problem is that I've got two separate programs: the https webserver and the websocket "game" server.

When i try connecting to the ws server i get:

> Uncaught DOMException: The operation is insecure.

I only found instructions on how to set up wss by creating a https server, but i already have one.

Do i need to combine the two programs?

Could i maybe just serve the single page for the game with http?

Is there some other technology, which doesn't have these security restrictions? (i don't care about encryption for the websockets)

Comment: Best approach would be to use a proper server for both (don't use `file://`), and for both to be on HTTPS. They *could* be the same server (in a single app), or they could be on separate servers (both with HTTPS support), depending on how you want to organize things.

Comment: What prevents you from upgrading your "gameserver" to https?

Comment: @derpirscher 
I used [greenlock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/greenlock) to get https for my webserver. I tried doing that for my "gameserver" , it says it is serving, but i cannot connect by any means. [i used this example](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js/src/branch/master/examples/websockets/server.js). I also referenced the greenlock.d directory of my webserver. That didn't seem to cause any errors ,but I am unsure if it actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work:

Instead of wanting to use the https server from the web-server, i "upgraded" my http-server for the "gameserver" to https.
 I didn't want to "create" another https server, because i thought it would cause errors, but i already made a http server indirectly anyways, with  `new WebSocketServer.Server({ port: PORT });`.

To create the https server and use it for the WebSocketServer i used this code:

```js
    let cert = fs.readFileSync(pathtocertkey, "utf8");
    let key = fs.readFileSync(pathtopublickey, "utf8");
    let options = {key: key, cert: cert};
    let server = require("https").createServer(options);
    const wss = new WebSocketServer.Server({ server: server});
```

After that i could listen to any port with `server.listen(PORT,callback)`.
I also wasn't sure how or if i could get the cert i got with [greenlock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/greenlock). But I found it under`greenlock.d/live/[yourdomain]/`
With greenlock.d being the configDir specified in `greenlock.init(options)`.

For the client i need to connect like this :
`ws = new WebSocket("wss://mydomain:"+PORT);`'